# Can't import models on python console in Pycharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am trying to import one of my models in Python Console in PyCharm and I am getting the following error:

```
    from damage.models import Damage
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.3.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 20, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\projects\django\deya\damage\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.3.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 20, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\projects\django\deya\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.3.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 20, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\projects\django\deya\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\projects\django\deya\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 100, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "C:\projects\django\deya\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 244, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\projects\django\deya\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 127, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Everything else in my project works fine.

I am able to import my models when I run

```
python manage.py shell
```

from command line or even PyCharm Terminal.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you have a virtualenv set up?

Comment: Yes I do `C:\projects\django\deya\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.3.3\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py" 6550 6551` is the command when Python console starts. `C:\projects\django\deya\venv` is the virtualenv

Comment: what do you get if you run ```python manage.py runserver``` have you included the app in INSTALLED_APPS where the Damage model is defined?

Comment: `python manage.py runserver` executes fine and I also included the app in INSTALLED_APPS

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think it is possible to work with `Django` outside of the `python manage.py runserver` initialisation. What happens when you run this in the terminal, do you receive any errors?

Comment: It's actually possible to run Django outside of manage.py, in your script you just have to include: ```from django.conf import settings
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from django.core.management import call_command

application = get_wsgi_application()``` and also add DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable so django knows where to load the settings.py file from ...

Comment: @Lingster Yes, outside of the normal configuration setup - it's possible I guess. :) I'm assuming no prior or very beginner level Django experience for this user.

Comment: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is defined in project settings. I define it manually by `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "deya.settings")`. I tried also `import django` and 'django.setup()'. After all these i am getting the error 'RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.`

Comment: @kpk Hi, the deflation of app label is certainly because you’re running it outside of the python manage.py runserver.

Answer (score 0):

This is what solve the issue for me.

- Once you're project is running using the IDE interface.
- Open the python console and:

  1. `import django`
  2. `from {YOPUR MODEL} import {MODEL_NAME, ...}`